# How to identify a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

> Suppose that a curve $\mathbf\gamma$ in $\mathbb R^3$ has constant strictly positive curvature function $\mathbf\kappa(s)$, and constant non-zero torsion function $\mathbf\tau(s)$. Prove that the curve is a helix.

I think it is easier to work backward here. First I can show that a helix satisfies the two conditions on curvature and torsion. Second, I want to use the fundamental theorem of curves to show that curve satisfying these two conditions must be a helix. However, there is a gap here. The fundamental theorem requires the function of curvature and torsion to uniquely identify a curve up to rigid motion. However, this question only gives a qualitative description of the two functions. How to make up this gap, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it. If $\kappa=a/c$ and $\tau=b/c$, where $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, then your curve is congruent to (differs by a rigid motion from) the circular helix $\alpha(t)=(a\cos t, a\sin t, bt)$. Given $\kappa$ and $\tau$, you can determine $a$ and $b$ by algebra.

Comment: Do you mean that I don't even need to know the specific forms of curvature and torsion, please? Only the qualitative descriptions are enough, please? Thank you.

Comment: Well, as I said, to give a complete solution, you should find $a$ and $b$ explicitly.

Comment: I think this proves that the helix has constant curvature and torsion and fits these constants with the given constants. But the OP needs every curve with constant curvature and torsion is a helix

Comment: No, @semsem, the Fundamental Theorem of Curves shows they differ by a rigid motion.

Comment: Now I understand, "a curve is completely determined by its curvature and torsion"

Answer (score 2):

A curve in $\mathbb R^3$ can be uniquely (up to a rigid motion) reproduced once its curvature and torsion are known. If ${T}$, ${N}$ and ${B}$ is its moving orthogonal frame (tangent, norma and binormal), then they satisfy the system (Frenet-Serret)
$$
T'=kN,\\
N'=-kT-\tau B,\\
B'=\tau N. 
$$
or
$$
H'=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & \kappa & 0\\ -\kappa & 0 & -\tau \\ 0 & \tau & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\,H
$$
where $H$ is the matrix with rows $T,N$ and $B$.

Next, if we the exponential of $A=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & \kappa & 0\\ -\kappa & 0 & -\tau \\ 0 & \tau & 0
\end{matrix}\right)$, then
$$
H(t)=\exp(tA)H(0),
$$
and if $T(t)$ is the first row, then $\gamma(t)=\gamma(0)+\int_0^t T(s)\,ds.$